# Two at a time string algorithms?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

Is there a way to do the following in a single command (in order to avoid the test)

```
if (mystring.find_first_not_of("X") != std::string::npos) {
    mystring.erase(0, mystring.find_first_not_of("X"));
}
```

Comment: You can store the result of `find_first_not_of` in a variable. You'll still have to do the test but it's going to be a super cheap, constant time operation.

Comment: You could probably fudge `std::find` and a comparator. Edit: Just as I pressed enter...

Comment: Also, I sense an XY problem here. Your code removes leading `'0'` characters. Are you trying to parse or shorten integer strings? Because you might very well _not_ have to remove leading `'0'` characters.

Comment: @zneak : not at all, I could have written "A" or "B"

Comment: In fact "remove leading something" now to avoid any misconception.

Comment: @DrewDormann But it doesn't; it means "remove leading `0`s, unless the string is just `0`s".

Comment: @AlexChamberlain +1.  Coffee time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mystring.erase(0, std::max(0, (std::make_signed<std::string::size_type>::type)
                           mystring.find_first_not_of('X')));
```

Or without C++11:

```
mystring.erase(0, std::max(0, (int)mystring.find_first_not_of('X')));
```